# Find the indexes of all regex matches?

Tags: python, regex, indexing

I'm parsing strings that could have any number of quoted strings inside them (I'm parsing code, and trying to avoid PLY).  I want to find out if a substring is quoted, and I have the substrings index.  My initial thought was to use re to find all the matches and then figure out the range of indexes they represent.

It seems like I should use re with a regex like `\"[^\"]+\"|'[^']+'` (I'm avoiding dealing with triple quoted and such strings at the moment).  When I use findall() I get a list of the matching strings, which is somewhat nice, but I need indexes.

My substring might be as simple as `c`, and I need to figure out if this particular `c` is actually quoted or not.

Comment: Sounds like the job not suitable for regexes.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

This is what you want: ([source](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer))

> ```
> re.finditer(pattern, string[, flags])
> ```
>
> Return an iterator yielding MatchObject instances over all
>   non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string. The string is
>   scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. Empty
>   matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of
>   another match.

You can then get the start and end positions from the MatchObjects.

e.g.

```
[(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(pattern, string)]
```

Comment: Note that you can actually use `m.span()` to get `(m.start(), m.end())` (and the default group argument is `0`, so that can be omitted).

Comment: Brilliant. Was looking for exactly this.

Comment: attention, it fails in this case: base_str = "GATATATGCATATACTT"
sub_str = "ATAT", the result should be [(1,5), (3, 7), (9, 13)], but it turns out [(1, 5), (9, 13)]

Comment: @unionx if you have better solution, this is your choice.

Comment: @unionx: finditer(), as per the documentation, returns non-overlapping matches.

Comment: A [much more recent example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-do-we-use-re-finditer-method-in-Python-regular-expression), with 2018 syntax

Answer (score 6):

To get indice of all occurences:

```py
S = input() # Source String 
k = input() # String to be searched
import re
pattern = re.compile(k)
r = pattern.search(S)
if not r: print("(-1, -1)")
while r:
    print("({0}, {1})".format(r.start(), r.end() - 1))
    r = pattern.search(S,r.start() + 1)
```

Comment: Good hint. If you compile before, it takes less memory and time.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue:

```py
pattern=r"(?=(\"[^\"]+\"|'[^']+'))"
```

Then use the following to get all overlapping indices:

```py
indicesTuple = [(mObj.start(1),mObj.end(1)-1) for mObj in re.finditer(pattern,input)]
```