# Finding the position of a pattern using the re module in Python

Tags: python, regex, position

I looked through a bunch of methods the `re` module provides, but I couldn't seem to find one that gives the *position* of a pattern.

For example, consider the following code:

```
import re

text = '23132102301211213302'

x=re.findall(r'21',text)

print x
```

Output:

```
['21', '21', '21']
```

---

I just get a list of 21's as my output, which isn't useful for my purposes. I was wondering if there was a method similar to findall, which gives the positions of 21's, and not just 21's (i.e the first 21 occurs in position 4, the second in position 11...)

2313***21***02301211213302
--> position: 4

23132102301***21***1213302
--> position: 11

23132102301211***21***3302
--> position: 14

So the desired output should be [4,11,14]. Is there a `re` method for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519565/find-the-indexes-of-all-regex-matches-in-python

Answer (score 2):

[`re.finditer()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer) gives you [`MatchObjects`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects) which among other things make the position available.

The beginning of the match object `m` is given by `m.start()`, and the end by `m.end()` if you want that too.

Comment: Thank you very much friend. That method took care of the problem :]