# How to find the index of exact match?

Tags: python, regex, exact-match

I know how to use python to report exact match in a string:

```
import re
word='hello,_hello,"hello'
re.findall('\\bhello\\b',word)
['hello', 'hello']
```

How do I report the indices of the exact matches? (in this case, 0 and 14)

Comment: Check out this link. Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the indexes of all regex matches in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519565/find-the-indexes-of-all-regex-matches-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
[(g.start(), g.group()) for g in re.finditer('\\b(hello)\\b',word)]
# [(0, 'hello'), (14, 'hello')]
```

Answer (score 1):

instead use word.find('hello',x)

```
word = 'hello,_hello,"hello'
tmp = 0
index = [] 
for i in range(len(word)):
   tmp = word.find('hello', tmp)
   if tmp >= 0:
       index.append(tmp)
       tmp += 1
```

Comment: `str.find` will return all occurrences, without respecting the word boundary condition as desired in the question.