# Finding the position of words in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, search

***My Task***

I am trying to find the position of words appearing in a string using regex

***Code***

```
import re

# A random string

mystr = "there not what is jake can do for you ask what you play do for spare jake".upper() 

match = re.search(r"[^a-zA-Z](jake)[^a-zA-Z]", mystr)

print match.start(1)
```

***Output***

```
18
```

***Expected output***

I would expect my output to contain the positions of the string `jake`:

```
5, 17
```

*EDIT: 
To clarify, I'm trying to identify the position of words. I believe what I have done is found the index and am unsure how to make it work as I expect*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, he wants word position, not character

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: it is a rhetorical question. Wiktor wants to point out the wrong approach. The string is made out of characters, not of words. The OP is getting the index of the first character occurence.

Comment: Is this even possible with only regex? I don't think so.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/a/12054409/3832970

Comment: `r'[\s]*(jake)[\s]*'` would already be a better Regex, but I don't think this is possible with Regex only

Comment: Please ref [Find the indexes of all regex matches in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519565/find-the-indexes-of-all-regex-matches-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the "ordinal" positions of search string `jake` in the input string use the following approach:

```
mystr = "there not what is jake can do for you ask what you play do for spare jake"
search_str = 'jake'

result = [i+1 for i,w in enumerate(mystr.split()) if w.lower() == search_str]
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[5, 17]
```

---

- `enumerate(mystr.split())` - to get enumerated object (pairs of items with their positions/indices)
- `w.lower() == search_str` - if a word is equal to search string

Comment: I was writting pretty much the same, but you were faster. Easy and simple solution without using RegEx.

Comment: He asked using regex, right?

Comment: @cezar, yes, no need regex in this case and import re

Answer (score 4):

Try this way:

```
mystr = "there not what is jake can do for you ask what you play do for spare jake"
result = [index+1 for index,word in enumerate(mystr.split()) if word=='jake']
result
```

Output:

```
[5, 17]
```

Comment: you were 12 seconds later

Comment: And I was even more late than that, so discarded my answer. But you know that it takes much more than 12 seconds to write an answer. Speed is good, but accuracy is more important.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest we are in same time space :)