# finding number of repetitive string occurrences

Tags: python, substring

My line is:

```
line = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbbbbbbbbbbbbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbbbbbbbbbbb"
```

How can I find number of patches of "xxxxx" in `line`? For example above the answer would be `2`.

Note that the number of `'x's` may vary.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: i tried s.find('x') and s.rfind('x'), but it does not give result i want

Comment: in my lines there are at least 3 xs are there

Answer (score 3):

This is a good example of where regex can be quite useful. I'm not the world's best at regex, but here's a snippet that works:

```
import re

line = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbbbbbbbbbbbbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbbbbbbbbbbb"
patches = len(re.findall(r"(x+)", line))
```

This works by matching any group of 1 or more 'x' no matter how long.

Comment: This is another one line solution. Thanx

Comment: how can i get starting and ending index of each such patch?

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519565/find-the-indexes-of-all-regex-matches-in-python) a question that does what you're looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` to group each "patch" and then count the number of occurances:

```
from itertools import groupby

line = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbbbbbbbbbbbbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbbbbbbbbbbb'
number_of_x = sum(ch == 'x' for ch, _ in groupby(line))
```

Comment: that's seriously beautiful!

Comment: Thanks Jonas. It works perfectly. I wonder when would I be able to write code like this.