# returns the location of the first item for the whole list instead of each item's location?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

this code is supposed to read a text file of a genome, and given a pattern, should return how many times the pattern occurred, and its location.
instead, it returns the number of occurrences and the location of the first occurrence only.
[this is an example of running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOrpm.png) instead of returning the location of the 35 occurrences, it returns the first location 35 times.

```
# open the file with the original sequence
myfile = open('Vibrio_cholerae.txt')

# set the file to the variable Text to read and scan
Text = myfile.read()

# insert the pattern
Pattern = "TAATGGCT"

PatternLocations = []

def PatternCount(Text,Pattern):
    count = 0
    for i in range (len(Text)-len(Pattern)+1):
        if Text [i:i+len(Pattern)] == Pattern:
            count +=1
            PatternLocations.append(Text.index(Pattern))
    return count


# print the result of calling PatternCount on Text and Pattern.
print (f"Number of times the Pattern is repeated: {PatternCount(Text,Pattern)} time(s).")
print(f"List of Pattern locations: {PatternLocations}")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3519565/967621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did

```
PatternLocations.append(Text.index(Pattern))
```

`.index` with single argument does

```
Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found
```

you should do

```
PatternLocations.append(i)
```

as you does find location yourself without using index but using

```
if Text [i:i+len(Pattern)] == Pattern:
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked. 
i thought about returning i but what i did was different
it tried 
    PatternLocations.append(Text.index(i)) 
but that gave me an error obviously.

Answer (score 0):

instead of itearting throughout the text I would suggest that you use `re`.

Here's a snippet:

```
from re import finditer
for match in finditer(pattern, Text):
    print(match.span(), match.group())
```

From a custom example I used (`pattern='livraison'`) it returned something like that:

```
>>>(18, 27) livraison
>>>(80, 89) livraison
>>>(168, 177) livraison
>>>(290, 299) livraison
```