# Finding indexes of substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to code a program to find the index of multiple substrings of a string but I am stuck! See the examples bellow:

```
Find : 'yes'
Input = 'adnyesdapodyesndudndnyesae'
Output = [3,11,21]
```

```
Find : 'b'
Input = 'bbbbbbb'
Output = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: I've used substring methods from python but they only input the first time python spots the word, if the word is inside the string multiple times it wont let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the indexes of all regex matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519565/find-the-indexes-of-all-regex-matches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str1 = "adnyesdapodyesndudndnyesae" #The String
substr = "yes" #The Substring
res = [i for i in range(len(str1)) if str1.startswith(substr, i)]
print(str(res))
```

The third line basically runs a `list comprehension` method wherein using a for loop you check for occurences of a substring in the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
F = 'yes'
I = 'adnyesdapodyesndudndnyesae'

[n for n in range(len(I)) if I.find(F, n) == n]
```

Here we are using the `find()` method of string to get the index

```
[3, 11, 21]

F = 'b'
I = 'bbbbbbb'

[n for n in range(len(I)) if I.find(F, n) == n]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

#2 A simple while loop solution:

```
def findall(f, s):
    l = []
    i = -1
    while True:
        i = s.find(f, i+1)
        if i == -1:
            return l
        l.append(s.find(f, i))

print(findall(F, I))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the range of numbers based on the string lengths then take the slice of input string from `i` to `n` number of characters where `n` is the length of the string to find, then compare for equality. You can implement using List-Comprehension:

```py
>>> n = len(Find)
>>> [i for i in range(len(Input)-n) if Input[i:i+n]==Find]
# Output:
[3, 11, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Pythons built-in module re to do this easily:

```py
import re

def find_all_occurances(string, sub_string):
    return [match.start() for match in re.finditer(sub_string, string)]
```

If you want to include overlapping matches with re, you can do:

```py
import re

def find_all_occurances(string, sub_string):
    return [match.start() for match in re.finditer(f"(?={sub_string})", string)]
```

Otherwise, this is easily done using plain Python:

```py
def find_all_occurances(string, sub_string):
    occurances = []

    start = 0

    while (start := string.find(sub_string, start)) != -1:
        occurances.append(start)
        start += len(sub_string)  # use start += 1 to find overlapping matches

    return occurances
```