# How to get all the indexes of leading zeroes using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Using Regex in Python (library re (only)), I want to create a function that gives me the position of all leading 0s in a string.

For example, if the string was: My house has 01 garden and 003 rooms.
I would want me the function to return 13, 27 and 28.

I tried for example:

```
import re
string = "My house has 01 garden and 003 rooms."
pattern = "(0+)[1-9]\d*"

print(re.findall(pattern,string))
```

Obviously, the output gives me the matches but no position...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the indexes of all regex matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519565/find-the-indexes-of-all-regex-matches)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

```py
import re

text = "My house has 01 garden and 003 rooms."
pattern = re.compile(r"\b0+")


def leading_zeros_index(s: str) -> list:
    return [i for m in pattern.finditer(s) for i in range(m.start(), m.end())]


print(leading_zeros_index(text))
```

output:

```
[13, 27, 28]
```

Basically you use `.finditer()` in order to get the match object, then you create a `range()` object from match object's [`.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start) and [`.end()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.end).

I used `\b0+` as the pattern. There is no need to check the other characters come after zeros. `\b` is word boundary, here means, zeros should be at the start of the words.

Comment: This looks great, thank you!
I am just beginning to understand regex, so i need to ask, the r in (r"\b0+") is needed why?

Comment: @KatharinaBöhm That `r""` creates a "raw-string". You should almost always use it for regex patterns because it prevents Python from escaping some escape-sequences. Try to run `print("hi\nbye")` and `print(r"hi\nbye")` to see the difference.